# Select all files with file picker metro apps windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
    OutputTextBlock.Text = "Picked photo: " + file.Name;
}
else
{
    OutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
}
```

**How do I add** `openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".*");` **means show all file types in file picker?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.. the correct syntax is `openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");`

From the [FileTypeFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.filetypefilter) documentation:

> The [File picker sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=234890) demonstrates how to **show files of any type** in
>   the file picker for the user to pick from.

Where the code from the sample:

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

Comment: What the heck...!!! how did i miss it from the sample code. Thanks @nemesv for the help.